# I am trying for corner radius to view which is placed inside UITableView. It doesn't work for me

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, rounded-corners

I am trying to give corner radius to UIView which is placed in UITableViewCell. I need to display section like corner radius for every section so I am giving first cell to top right and top left corner radius and for the last cell to bottom right and bottom left corner radius. But it's not works for me.

Here is my code:
This is for the first cell (row) of UITableView

```
cell.viewMain.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10.0)
cell.layoutSubviews()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

This is for the last cell (row) of UITableView

```
cell.viewMain.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10.0)
cell.layoutSubviews()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Extension which I am using:

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

I need output like this:

[image]

Comment: try `cell.viewMain.clipsToBounds = true`

Comment: Tried, not working

Comment: then in your roundCorners method bound is zero

Comment: What are you getting as output?

Comment: I got solution but using UIImage. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem a while back and what i was missing was that the table view is reusing the cells so we have to revert all the other cells to their default state.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! myCell

    let isFirstCell = indexPath.row == 0
    let isLastCell = indexPath.row == TotalRowsCount - 1

    if isFirstCell && isLastCell {
        cell.viewMain.topBottomRounded()
    } else if isFirstCell {
        cell.viewMain.topRounded()
    } else if isLastCell {
        cell.viewMain.bottomRounded()
    } else {
        // THIS IS THE KEY THING
        cell.viewMain.defaultStateForBorders()
    }

    return cell
}
```

I have run your Code and its working fine except this thing.

where helping methods using your extension method are:

```
extension UIView {

func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    layer.mask = mask
}

func topRounded() {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 10.0)
}

func bottomRounded() {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10.0)
}

func topBottomRounded() {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight,.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 10.0)
}

func defaultStateForBorders() {
    self.roundCorners(corners: [], radius: 0)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.JavedMultani i've run the code and i got the desired out put. maybe you want to achieve something different, i'm adding the out put for the above code.

Comment: Thanks man, I am using this with section. I got soultion by using UIImage because I have no time.